# Elegant way of writing nested if statements (containing different conditions)

Tags: python, if-statement

I have 4 variables (containing a relative value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0) and I want to check that at least 2 of these variables are above 0.01 and 1 of these 2 has to be above 0.05. I have written the following chunk:

```
if rel1 > 0.05:
    if rel2 > 0.01 or rel3 > 0.01 or rel4 > 0.01:
        print "Yay" # Filler line
elif rel2 > 0.05:
    if rel1 > 0.01 or rel3 > 0.01 or rel4 > 0.01:
        print "Yay" # Filler line
elif rel3 > 0.05:
    if rel1 > 0.01 or rel2 > 0.01 or rel4 > 0.01:
        print "Yay" # Filler line
elif rel4 > 0.05:
    if rel1 > 0.01 or rel2 > 0.01 or rel3 > 0.01:
        print "Yay" # Filler line
```

I however find this code looking rather icky and assume that there must be a more pythonic way to do this? I have been experimenting with the following (doesn't work but shows how I would expect that it's solvable):

```
for i in range(1,4):
  val = "rel" + str(i)
    if val > 0.05 # Got stuck on this line
      # dynamically generate the other 3 if's :
        # Do the logic
```

The problem here is that instead of the actual value, it just yields the name (ie rel1) because it is a string and I am a bit unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Your's is good way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
l = [rel1, rel2, rel3, rel4]
if any(item > 0.05 for item in l) and sum(item > 0.01 for item in l) >= 2:
    print "Yay"
```

(`sum()` works this way because boolean `True` has the numeric value `1`; thanks @falsetru for suggesting this)

Comment: Yay! (shouldn't it be >=3?)

Comment: `sum(1 for item in l if item > 0.01)` can be replaced with `sum(item > 0.01 for item in l)`

Comment: @unutbu: "At least 2" includes 2, doesn't it?

Comment: @falsetru: Oh, absolutely! Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker: actually, shouldn't it be >=4, since all the items have to be > 0.01.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I like your solution since it uses an idea that I had not considered (the counting of sum(condition)). Much appreciated.

Comment: @unutbu, No, inner(?) conditions are connected with `or`, not `and`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = [rel1, rel2, rel3, rel4]
r.sort()
if r[-1] > 0.5 and r[-2] > 0.1:
    print "Yay"
```

Comment: How about using `-1`, `-2` instead of `3`, `2`?